# Conditionally print VC macros

Tags: conditionals

How might I go about conditionally printing a macro? I know this exists for graphics (`\includegraphics`) and there's `ifdraft` for the rest. For example, using `fancyhdr` I have the following (simplified) document:

`preamble.sty`

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\ifdraft {\cfoot{\textit{\VCDateISO - \GITAbrHash}}} {}
```

`test.tex`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{preamble}
\immediate\write18{./vc}
\input{vc}
\begin{document}
FOO BAR BAZ
...
...
\ifdraft %{VC Macros}{}
\end{document}
```

Does this make sense if I want to only print the VC stats when in draft mode?

Comment: @Werner https://ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft?lang=en

Comment: I would probably use it in the following way: `\cfoot{\ifdraft{\textit{\VCDateISO - \GITAbrHash}}{}}`. Note that you still need to set `\pagestyle{fancy}` in order to see a change in the headers/footers.